# Translation suggestion for the name of a book

Tags: word-choice, translation

I'm not a native English speaker, and trying to translate the name of a book into English. It's a book about how to travel by bike, and the name I can come up with is *An alternative way to travel -- by bike*, which doesn't look like a book name at all. The name should inlcude two ideas:

- It's an *ALTERNATIVE* way of traveling, since by-car is more common than by-bike when traveling. Kind of a *new*, *unconventional* way.
- It's *BY BIKE*

Comment: What's the original title?

Comment: Actually I really, really like **"An alternative way to travel -- by bike"**.  It's part of the "new honest". I like it.  (BTW personally I prefer "alternate" to "alternative" - but that's a tricky decision in English.)

Comment: I would not understand the choice of alternate over alternative. To me alternate is when you one day take the bike, another day take the bus or car

Comment: @JustinGreer The original Title is in Chinese: "换种方式去旅行 -- 骑行”

Comment: This is an interesting subject, but there doesn't appear to be a question. Can you include a question? Are you asking if what you've suggested, is grammatical?

Comment: @mplungjan - As a native Brit, I use 'alternative' the same way you do. However, in US English 'alternate' is very commonly used instead of 'alternative'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I say, I love your suggestion,

```
An alternative way to travel -- by bike.
```

Some other suggestions...

```
The biking alternative.
```

or

```
Bike! The alternative way to go.
```

ad similar variations.........

Comment: Thank you for supporting my suggestion! I think I'll pick one between the first and the third options.

Answer (score 3):

Your proposed title is fine.  Here is another.  ("**Touring**" is what is usually used for bike trips. It emphasizes traveling and visiting places leisurely.)

*Touring By Bike, An Alternative Way to Travel*, where the last phrase is a subtitle.

Or maybe *See the Country* (or *Visit XYZ*) instead of *Travel*.

[FWIW, I took a 2-month bike trip many years ago, and will never forget it. *Great* way to see the country (any country) and its inhabitants (including cows etc.).]